# CMake clang-analyzer and jenkins

Tags: c++, jenkins, clang-static-analyzer

So I have found a plugin for Jenkins to view clang-analyzer output, but it seems to depend on my using xcode.

I've also figured out the easy path to using clang-analyzer with cmake.

But is there a way to get a Jenkins visualization of clang-analyzer output if my build is cmake?

Comment: How did you use clang with cmake ?